# в клиент-сервере на RMI исключение java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

Tags: java, rmi

Клиент - сервер на RMI
При старте под intelij idea, на стороне выбрасывается исключение

```
Exception in thread "main" java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Application (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at main.java.Client.main(Client.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Application (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadProxyClass(LoaderHandler.java:556)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadProxyClass(RMIClassLoader.java:646)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadProxyClass(RMIClassLoader.java:311)
    at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveProxyClass(MarshalInputStream.java:265)
```

Помогите пожалуйста пофиксить.

СЕРВЕР:
интерфейс

```
 public interface Application extends Remote {
    public int add(int a, int b) throws RemoteException;
    }
```

реализован в

```
public class ApplicationImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Application, Serializable {

    protected ApplicationImpl() throws RemoteException {
    }

    public int add(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

*класс для старта:*

```
public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException, MalformedURLException, AlreadyBoundException {
        Application application = new ApplicationImpl();
        Application stub = (Application) UnicastRemoteObject.toStub(application);
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(8888);

        registry.rebind("ClientRegister", stub);
    }
}
```

======================
КЛИЕНТ:
тот же интерфейс Application.
Для старта использую код:

```
public class Client {

public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException, NotBoundException {
    Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("127.0.0.1", 8888);

        registry.lookup("ClientRegister");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась переносом своих классов из пакета src.main.java в дефолтный пакет, то есть в src.
Пакетирование в RMI не тривиально.